# Building JSON data using PHP

Tags: php, json

I would like to produce the following JSON output using PHP

```
{
"dataid": "An optional sourcetable identifier",
"columns": [
    {
        "colvalue": "Status",
        "coltext": "Status",
        "header": "Status",
        "sortbycol": "Status",
        "groupbyrank": null,
        "pivot": true,
        "result": false
    },
    {
        "colvalue": "Priority",
        "coltext": "Priority",
        "header": "Priority",
        "sortbycol": "Priority",
        "dataid": "An optional id.",
        "groupbyrank": 4,
        "pivot": false,
        "result": false
    },
    {
        "colvalue": "Team",
        "coltext": "Team",
        "header": "Team",
        "sortbycol": false,
        "dataid": "An optional id.",
        "groupbyrank": 1,
        "pivot": false,
        "result": false
    },
    {
        "colvalue": "Module",
        "coltext": "Module",
        "header": "Module",
        "sortbycol": "Module",
        "dataid": "An optional id.",
        "groupbyrank": 2,
        "pivot": false,
        "result": false
    },
    {
        "colvalue": "SLA",
        "coltext": "SLA",
        "header": "SLA",
        "sortbycol": "SLA",
        "dataid": "An optional id.",
        "groupbyrank": 3,
        "pivot": false,
        "result": false
    },
    {
        "colvalue": "Score",
        "coltext": "Score",
        "header": "Score",
        "sortbycol": "Score",
        "groupbyrank": null,
        "pivot": false,
        "result": true
    }
],
"rows": [
    {
        "Team": "Technical",
        "Module": "BASIS",
        "SLA": "Critical",
        "Priority": "High",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Score": "1",
        "Score2": "18.27"
    },
    {
        "Team": "Technical",
        "Module": "BASIS",
        "SLA": "Critical",
        "Priority": "High",
        "Status": "In Progress",
        "Score": "1",
        "Score2": "18.27"
    },
 **** MORE ENTRIES ARE ITERATED BASED ON SQL ROW ***
]
```

}

However i am stuck on how to combine my array which are hardcoded and my dynamic data (taken from MySQL row).

The following is my PHP code to generate the *column* and *dataid* which is static

```
$test = array(
        "dataid" => 'An optional sourcetable identifier',
        "columns" => array(
            array(
                'colvalue' => 'Status',
                'coltext' =>'Status',
                'header' =>'Status',
                'sortbycol' => 'Status',
                'groupbyrank' => null,
                'pivot' => true,
                'result' => false
            ),
            array(
                'colvalue' => 'Priority',
                'coltext' => 'Priority',
                'header' => 'Priority',
                'sortbycol' => 'Priority',
                'dataid' => 'An optional id.',
                'groupbyrank' => 4,
                'pivot' => false,
                'result' => false
            ),
        )
    );
```

What i am stuck with is how do combine it with my row data? Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: `$test['rows'] = $yourRowDataAsArray;`

Comment: @colburton Sweet... it works. You should put this as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ammend existing arrays just by using a new key:

```
$test['rows'] = $yourRowDataAsArray;
```